# Run multiple SQL queries in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code:

```
function report1() { 
  
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, name,passward);
  var sql =  conn.prepareStatement("SET @sql = NULL; ");
  var group_concat_max_len =  conn.prepareStatement("SET @@group_concat_max_len = 40000; ");
  var sel_query =  conn.prepareStatement("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT \
      CONCAT(' IFNULL(COUNT(case when pt.name =  ', '\'', name, '\'',' THEN 1 END),0) AS ', replace(name, ' ', '_')) \
      ) INTO @sql \
       from propertytypes; ");
  
  var set_query = conn.prepareStatement(" SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.name as city,date(pr.created_at) as date,' \
                     ,@sql, \
                  ', IFNULL(COUNT(pr.id),0) AS Total \
                  from properties pr \
                 LEFT JOIN cities c on c.id = pr.city_id \
                 LEFT JOIN propertytypes pt on pt.id = pr.propertytype_id where  pr.status = \'Active\' \
                 group by city, date(pr.created_at) \
                 ORDER BY date,Total DESC');");
  
  
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(" PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; ");
  var execute = conn.prepareStatement(" EXECUTE stmt; ");
  var deallocate =conn.prepareStatement( " DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; ");
  
   sql.executeQuery(); 
   group_concat_max_len.executeQuery();
   sel_query.executeQuery();
   set_query.executeQuery();
   stmt.executeQuery();  
   execute.executeQuery();
   deallocate.executeQuery();
 
  
   var mat1 = [];
   mat1[0] = [];
  
  for (j=0; j<result1.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++){
  mat1[0].push(result1.getMetaData().getColumnName(j+1));
 }
  
  var row = 0;  
  while(result1.next()) {
   mat1[row+1] = [];
    
   for(var i=0; i<1; i++) {     // four fields per record
      mat1[row+1][i] = result1.getString(i+1);
    }
    for(var i=1; i<result1.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {     // four fields per record
      mat1[row+1][i] = result1.getInt(i+1);
    }
    row++;
 }
 
  return mat1;
 
 }
```

But I get an error of "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' group by city, date(pr.created_at) ORDER BY ' at line 1 (line 74, file "asd")". in `set_query.executeQuery();`

But the mysql code is working in workbench. Can any one figure out the problem please?

Comment: You might get this error if you are running two `SELECT` on the same execution. It is suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498998/dynamic-sql-returns-syntax-error-on-google-apps-script-using-jdbc-and-mysql) to create a single connection then execute multiple SQL selects. *MySQL drivers sometimes prevent multiple statements in single `exec()` calls to prevent some forms of sql injection attacks.* Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks..I'll try that ...